# Как копировать в память данные по определенному пикселю?

Tags: javascript

Как по определенному пикселю снимать данные? Например, от начала браузера я бы нажимал на 10 пиксель по высоте и 20 по ширине и он бы мне копировал в память "Вы нажали на 10px (по высоте) 20px (по ширине)".

Ещё лучше было бы если: на каждый пиксель можно было бы прикрутить свой текст: 10px (высота) 20px (ширина) в память копировалось "-100 -200".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Есть такой элемент формы:

```
<INPUT TYPE="IMAGE"  SRC="..." HEIGHT="..." WIDTH="..." />
```

Он умеет генерировать x,y в который ткнул пользователь, но какого оно там цвета - не сообщает.

**UPDATE**:

Можно реализовать так (через jQuery):

```
<img src=".../map.gif" width="500" height="500" id="map" />
<script type="text/javascript">
    var perPixel = (2950+2950)/500;
    function fromPixel (c) {
        if (c > 250) {
            c = c * perPixel;
        }
        else {
            c = - (c * perPixel);
        }
        return c;
    }

    $("#map").click(
        function (e) {

           alert("Click on: " + fromPixel(e.clientX) + "," + fromPixel(e.clientY));
        }
    );
</script>
```

Песочница с данным примером [здесь](http://jsfiddle.net/chernomyrdin/zKC7g/)

Работа с clipboard в javascript достаточно мутная тема, ее лучше обсуждать отдельно.

**UPDATE 2**:

Касаемо подписей возможно использовать `<map>`

```
<img src=".../map.gif" width="500" height="500" usemap="#image-map" />
<map name="image-map">
  <area shape="rect" coords="0,0,1,1" alt="10x10" title="10x10" />
  <area shape="rect" coords="1,0,1,1" alt="20x10" title="20x10" />
...
</map>
```

Но тут может быть совсем другая система отработки, как то собственно генерация всех area на уровне javascript-а, так и привязка к ним обработчиков

Comment: Просто задание следущее есть карта:
500х500 (Например)

По нажатию на 20 пиксель на карте (по X и Y) нужно чтобы он отдавал значение не X Y а нужные мне... например
X:10 Y:20 нужно подменять на X:-2950 Y:-2500
и желательно сразу данные заносить в буфер

Comment: Уточни формулу преобразования из x:10,y:20 в x:-2950,y:-2500. Потом объясни что тебе нужно деть с буфером

Comment: Есть карта 500х500

0x0 это "-2950x-2950"
250х250 это "0x0"
500x500 это "2950x2950"

нужно по нажатию на тот или определенный пиксель высчитывает значения и копировать их в буфер. Например: "Вы взяли по X:2950 по Y:-2860" хотя в браузере был курсор кликнут на "X:500px Y:10px"

Конечно это все должно копироваться в буфер по клику